# Why can't I nest a DataGrid with a RowDetails Static Resource inside another?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Why can't the class GenderTemplateSelectorNested return a DataTemplate like it's parent? I've simplified the code for brevity.

Error

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'SchdUtil.GenderTemplateSelectorNested' is not a
>   valid value for property 'RowDetailsTemplate'.

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>

<l:GenderTemplateSelector x:Key="genderTemplateSelector">
    <l:GenderTemplateSelector.MaleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource genderTemplateSelectorNested}"
             ...
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </l:GenderTemplateSelector.MaleTemplate>
</l:GenderTemplateSelector>

<l:GenderTemplateSelectorNested x:Key="genderTemplateSelectorNested">
    <l:GenderTemplateSelector.MaleTemplateNested>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </l:GenderTemplateSelector.MaleTemplateNested>
</l:GenderTemplateSelectorNested>

</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource genderTemplateSelector}"
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind

```
public class GenderTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate MaleTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return MaleTemplate;
    }
}

public class GenderTemplateSelectorNested : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate MaleTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return MaleTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a template selector directly to the template. You need to use the template selector property instead.

```
<l:GenderTemplateSelector x:Key="genderTemplateSelector">
    <l:GenderTemplateSelector.MaleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid RowDetailsTemplateSelector="{StaticResource genderTemplateSelectorNested}"
             ...
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </l:GenderTemplateSelector.MaleTemplate>
</l:GenderTemplateSelector>
```

Comment: That's exactly it. I did it for the parent and didn't copy and paste it to the nested one, but used intellisense to write it and missed off the Selector bit. I feel so silly now. Thanks.